# Play 2.0 - auxiliary constructors in templates

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to have auxiliary constructors in Play 2.0 templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "constructor" I assume you mean argument list with different arguments. I don't know of a built-in way to do this, but I've only just starting learning Play.

However you can use the *Enhance My Instance*™ pattern to achieve the same effect:

Using the [to-do list example](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTodoList), say your `index.scala.html` template begins:

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[String])
```

In `Application.scala` you call this with

```
  def tasks    = Action { Ok(views.html.index(Task.all(), taskForm)) }
```

If you want to leave out the task list:

```
  implicit def enhanceIndex(index: views.html.index.type) = new {
    def apply(f: Form[String]) = index(List.empty, f)
  }
```

Now you can call it thus:

```
  def tasks2   = Action { Ok(views.html.index(taskForm)) }
```

This is essentially just the pimp-my-library pattern using `.type` to narrow the scope to a particular instance, in this case the `views.html.index` object.